# Problema com o Tomcat!

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Oi!

Estou estou tentando ativar o apache tomcat v7.0 no eclipse, porem quando vou ativa-lo acontece esse erro:

"-Djava.endorsed.dirs=\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules."

Como eu resolvo esse problema?

Eu ate pensei em por o tomcat 8.5, porém no meu eclipse só aparece até a versão 8.0 do apache e não quer aceitar a 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Se estiver usando o Java 10 para rodar o Eclipse, recomendo o downgrade para a versão 8.

Alguns problemas que eu tinha visto em relação a incompatibilidade do Tomcat com o Eclipse (por exemplo neste tópico aqui https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-tomcat-nao-funciona-61602), muitos problemas estão sendo causados porque estão sendo executados com a versão muito recente do Java/JDK, que possuem diversas mudanças em relação as anteriores.